# show dialog made from Activity without title

Tags: android, android-activity

I am showing a dialog made from Activity. The dialog activity has set no title in `onCreate()` callback:

```
public class MyDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set window feature no title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I defined a style for the activity:

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
     <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_bg</item>
 </style>
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
       android:name=".MyDialogActivity"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.MyDialog">
</activity>
```

But when I show the dialog, there is always a title(which shows my app's name) on the dialog.

It is weird **not only** because it still shows title, **but also** shows my app's name as title, as you can see, I haven't set any title. It looks like an Android default behaviour, but...how to get rid of the title?

(I am running on Android 5.1.1)

Comment: did you try `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: @SantanuSur in where to call it?

Comment: or you can also try a hacky method `getWindow().setTitle("");` in the activity ..@Leem

Comment: I know in activity, but which callback. My app crashes when add in onCreate() or onResume() , and getWindow().setTitle("") doesn't help either.

Comment: 1st one should crash cause you have disabled your actionBar from your style , but is the second one also crashing ?? you can allow title with the window (from styles ) ...just set it to empty ...should nt that work ??

Comment: 2nd one doesn't crash but it doesn't solve the problem. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: do only one thing.. extend class Activity instead of AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following style to your Activity for imitating a dialog:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.TranslucentDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorTransparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

where **colorTransparent** is the following:

```
<color name="colorTransparent">#64000000</color>
```

Then use it with:

```
<activity
     android:name=".MyDialogActivity"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.TranslucentDialog">
</activity>
```